# Create provisioning profile in iphone application

Tags: iphone, build, provisioning, user-profile

How can i build provisioning profile for deploying an iPhone application?

Comment: There is information inside the portal. [Certificates](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action), [Provisioning Profiles](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/provisioningprofiles/howto.action)

Answer (score 5):

Agree with above, but here is a the gist of it.

1. Register with Apple as an iPhone developer.
2. Give them 100 bucks to get your entrance into the club that can deploy apps onto phones.
3. Create your mobile provisioning in the [Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action) you gain access to in 2.
4. Build your apps using this mobile provisioning, in various scenarios. (Development, AdHoc distribution, deployment.)

Comment: Unfortunately I followed Apple's docs and still can't get this process to work.  Here I am months later (granted, I have other projects I am working on) and I still can't test on my iPhone.

Answer (score 4):

Please [read the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_developer_program_user_guide/iphone_developer_program_user_guide__standard_program_v2.4.pdf). If you have a specific problem feel free to update your question.

Comment: I've also suffered through some ridiculo0us frustrating time with xcode/apple providsioning and still can't deploy to my iphone.  I followed the provisioning wizard steps.  No luck.  It is one of the worst dev experiences I have ever had.

Comment: I wouldn't disagree that it's a frustrating process. Unfortunately the question gives no information about what options had been tried, what had succeeded, what had failed, error messages and so forth. How can you diagnose a problem when someone just says "it's broken"?

Comment: For those who know how to do it, a step-by-step simple set of instructions would help.  I have been to all the Apple documentation pages, and even run their worthless wizard.  After exhausting those options, it is no wonder to me that people can't even elaborate on what has been tried.  For me, getting the environment set up ranks as one of the all-time worst development experiences I have ever had.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your iPhone is not jailbroken. The process described is a bit of a pain but it's a one-time thing.