# How to get ipa file from Xcode to run an iPhone app in real device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, distribution, ipa

My client asked me to get the review of the app on which I am working. So, I want to get the ipa file and mobile provision file from Xcode 4.2 to share my app to run in real device. I have a paid account of apple with me. Please tell me the procedure to get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**STEP-1:**

You need to refer steps for **AdHoc Distribution**

I think you need to login with your credentials at [Developer Apple Login](https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?appIdKey=d4f7d769c2abecc664d0dadfed6a67f943442b5e9c87524d4587a95773750cea&path=//devcenter/ios/index.action)

Once you are logged in go through this link and read through it step by step.

I think this is the best solution you can get as this documentation guide is given by Apple

https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action

This has multiple steps like:

```
1. Generating a Certificate Signing Request

2. Submitting a Certificate Signing Request for Approval

3. Approving Certificate Signing Requests

4. Downloading and Installing Development Certificates

5. Saving your Private Key and Transferring to other Systems
```

I think if you read all this steps on the apple documentation at the given link then you don't need to refer to any other guide.

**STEP-2:**

Then just you need to download your certificates and provisioning profile.

**STEP-3:**

Just set the profile into your Project and Target Settings and then put proper Entitlements using "Entitlements.plist".

**STEP-4:**

Once you have done that, just set up your project in AdHoc Scheme.

**STEP-5:**

Clean your Project.

**STEP-6:**

Go to Product -> Click on Build For -> "Build For Archiving"

**STEP-7:**

Product -> Archive

Now your Archive can be obtained in your **Organizer** where in you can save it to disk with an IPA extension and send it your client.

**EDIT:**

Here are some of the useful links you can refer to for creating provisioning profile and IPA file:

[Create IPA file in Xcode 4.2, iOS 5.0 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817162/create-ipa-file-in-xcode-4-2-ios-5-0-beta)

http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/how-to-create-ipa-file-for-your-iphone-app-xcode-build-and-archive/

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Provisioning-Profile-for-iPhone

[Create provisioning profile in iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368062/create-provisioning-profile-in-iphone-application)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test application on device, then you need to create debug profile for it. You need to get it for your device from the provisioning section of developer portal. If you are creating the distribution profile, then you need to put the generated ipa file from build folder to itunes to install it on device.

Then you can install the application on device. But in that case you will not be able to see the logs.

So if you want to see the logs in Xcode console, Create a developer provisioning profile for the device & install it on XCode & then run the code on device using Xcode.

Maybe I think this is the entitlements.plist problem please follow the steps

In XCode, go to "new file" and select "code signing" in left box. Select the "Entitlements" file type. And change the name to "Entitlements.plist". Give the name in project getinfo entitlements plist please check the image below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

• Get their device ID and add their device to "Devices" in your iOS Provisioning Portal
Create or edit a distribution profile to include their device (wildcard app id or your app's app id)
• In Xcode: Product -> Archive
• In Xcode's Organizer: Go to archives and "Share" your archive. This creates an ipa that you can give to your client
• The client can install it in iTunes by adding the ipa and syncing apps (I haven't done this last step in a while)

OR

Get to know [testflight](http://www.testflightapp.com). Using testflight will replace the final step above and streamline the installation process for your client.

Answer (score 1):

After build with your provisioning profile or distribution for device(not simulator). You can follow this [tutorial.](http://benscheirman.com/2011/06/creating-proper-ipa-files-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, in fact I just did it.

After Xcode 6 you have to go to:

- Product-->Archive
- Then wait for it to finish. Then on the screen that pops up right click on your newly created archive-->Show file in finder
- Then head there with a terminal and run this command on that dir:

`xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath <PROJECT_NAME>.xcarchive -exportPath <PROJECT_NAME> -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "Name of Provisioning Profile"`

**DONE**

For example this command for me was:

`xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ACCESS\ 04-02-16\ 02.21.xcarchive/ -exportPath MyTestApp -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: eu.sudoplz.myTestApp"`

This created a `MyTestApp.ipa` file for me.

Comment: I got an error saying "xcodebuild: error: invalid option -exportFormat... is this an error you have encountered before?