# Allow Client to Test App Without Giving Them Code

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, beta

So I want to allow my client to try the app im developing, but I fear giving them the source prior to completion. Is there a way to send them a compiled version if they have x-code on their computer?

Comment: You can build using diawi.com and testFllight feature of Apple.

Comment: send him the diawi link. so that he can test on his mobile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to test iOS App.

1) [Testflight](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html)

---

2) [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) is another simple way. with using Diawi you have to upload an IPA and send client to onli url for download. it's Completely Wireless installation.

**Steps for Diawi........**

- Upload the application and its provisioning profile.
- Send the link to your testers, clients, friends or even use it yourself.
- Open the link in Safari on the iOS device and click on install.

> you have to add their iPhone’s UDID in the provisioning profile.

---

**3)** test In Simulator.
if client needs to test in simulator then send **.app** file to client.

**Steps for .app file**

- xCode window tab
- Organizer
- Right click to the archive you want to get app
- Show in finder
- Right click to (ProductName….). xcarchive file
- Show package contents
- Products
- Applications

Comment: Do Diawi is safe to use?

Comment: @RohitKP yes there are no any issue with diawi. because its give only wireless installation but UDID is required.

Answer (score 1):

Test-flight is the right way to achieve this.

- [TestFlight Beta Testing](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)
- [Tutorial to use test flight](http://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial)

You can also archive your build and send them the .ipa file to test. Don’t forget to add their iPhone’s UDID in the provisioning profile.

- [How to get ipa file from Xcode to run an iPhone app in real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595925/how-to-get-ipa-file-from-xcode-to-run-an-iphone-app-in-real-device)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the second solution would require the client to open the iTunes software, drag the IPA into "My Applications", connect the iPhone to his Mac and click "Sync". I recommend TestFairy.com, a good tool for sending test download links.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want them to test on Simulator or actual device? If its the actual device then you have to provision their device in your app provisioning profile and then create the IPA and send it. If you don't want to use TestFlight or other stuff you can send the IPA an ask them to install it via iTunes. If they have Xcode then they can install it from the Devices window.

Answer (score 0):

1. login developer account in xcode and browser
2. got to browser developer account then Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
   and devices then add udid of device here that you want to install the app.
3. In xcode generate signing certificate and fill  bundle identifier , versions and build
4. select the any iOS device in runner section.
5. go to product option then click on archive.

6.the click on distribute the app then select ad-hoc then next then automatic manage signing
Then export and choose location (document folder). Now go to diawi.com and upload the this ipa and share the link to that device to install the IPA