# I didn't get '+' button beside build option in iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My developer account is new account, I am uploading first app, but I am not getting + sign button beside build option in iTunes connect. like this image...

[image]

This is from https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html

In my iTunes page ...I am getting like this....

[image]

Image from Activity.

[image]

Comment: have you uploaded the build already ??

Comment: I uploaded from Xcode successfully...

Comment: can you see the build in `TestFlight` section?

Comment: NO it's not visible...(No build version in TestFlight.)

Comment: Can I upload one more time same archive file.

Comment: can you see the build in `Activity` section? it first appears there and after some time when it's processed then it appears in TestFlight.

Comment: I added new image from activity. Please see once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are uploading App, then in Activity Section it displays, and its status is processed  whenever the status is active then display + (Plus) button. You can add the build.

[image]

Comment: I added new image from activity. Please see once

Comment: @iOSDeveloper You are see in Activity Section , You build is in processing.

Comment: There is no processing msg in Activity section. I uploaded image file please click once. Please click Image form Activity .

Comment: Ya. So thats your build doesn't uploaded.

Comment: upload agains the build.

Comment: Can I upload the same archive file one more time.

Comment: Yes , because you have not uploaded here. you don't need to change version or build no.

Comment: Can u please tell me process how to upload through application loader.

Comment: its simple login of Apple account then drag and drop your IPA file and Next... Send Steps/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595925/how-to-get-ipa-file-from-xcode-to-run-an-iphone-app-in-real-device

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your app build is listed on iOS Builds screen with (Processing) status?

If not, then it will mean it did not deploy correctly from Xcode.

**Note:** you have to wait until Processing is finished before submitting your App to TestFlight.

Expected Activity tab screen view:
[image]

Comment: I added new image from activity. Please see once

Comment: **Your build was not deployed correctly to iTunes**. On **Activity** tab, **All Builds** section you should have build version listed. Try to upload build again via **Xcode** (it won't allow you to upload same build twice so it's good indication if previous time was successful or not). If upload is successful then you will see build in Activity straight away with a **Processing** status. If your build still is not there, make sure you are uploading to the right iTunes account. I have added screenshot of expected view to my original comment.

Answer (score -1):

Updated:
In my case. Apple sent an e-mail when they completed the automatic test stage. It may take time.