# Private iPhone app distribution given iPhone UDID?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an iPhone game, and someone is interested in a demo.

He gave me his iPhone UDID, but I am not really sure what to do with it. How exactly is he expecting me to give him a demo of my project? I certainly cannot upload it to the appstore, since it is not complete and I want it to stay private.

So, given an UID, how would you distribute your application? I think there would be some way to compile an .ipa or something and send it to him, not sure how would he install it.......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have purchased an apple developer account, what you will do is to make a [provision profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/368062/593709) for that device and download it and now you can send that app as archive to test it.

Lots of services are available, as I would suggest you to use [testflight](https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/)

[Here is a useful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40154/593709) discussion for testing on real device

Comment: I would definitely recommend testflightapp   +1

Comment: agree with @shein.  test flight is great.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a paid IPhone Developer account costing you $99. For sending the app to someone, rather than building it directly from Xcode to device via USB, you'll need to use a distribution provisioning profile. The apple developer site has really good instructions for walking you through obtaining this and setting up Xcode. Once you can Archive a build, follow the instructions in the answer in the link below for creating an ipa file. Once you have an ipa file built with your distribution profile, you'll be able to send that to your beta tester via email (or post it on a website) and they'll be able to access it.

[Xcode 4: create IPA file instead of .xcarchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265292/xcode-4-create-ipa-file-instead-of-xcarchive)

[TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) is also is really helpful for doing this, as well as providing a lot of other great features.

Comment: My post links to an answer that describes how to do this with xcode 4.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple steps:

1. Register device UDID that you need to demo on in Apple developer portal.
2. Pre-requisite - You need to register for this license of development which is 99$
3. Once you registered the Device. Create two things
   a. Provisioning profile
   b. Certificate

Once you are ready with these two things, you can provide them in your IDE to build the ipa file which is adhoc and will install/run only on registered devices