# Test App on my IPhone already have apple account

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create provisioning profile in iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368062/create-provisioning-profile-in-iphone-application)

i developed my iphone app and i want to test it on my IPhone. i have the account of dev.apple so no need to register. i just want to login with my account. what process i will perform for the getting `liencense`? im confused how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to test your application on real iPhone device then your should check below tutorial

[**Deploying iPhone Apps to Real Devices**](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices)

**Wei-Meng Lee** has described complete procedure step by step in easy way.

let me know if you get any trouble in this i have done!!

Answer (score -1):

You can easily search for that. There is nothing for confusion. Go through this link for enrolling your paid developer account and get licence and certificates